# AjaxStart issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to build a shopping website with ajax. When a user clicks the "add to cart" image. The little loading image will show next to the Add To Cart Image. The first click works fine and the image showed as I expected. However, the second and the following clicks appends more images on the first loading image(2nd:add two loading images, 3rd: add three images..6 total images after 3 clicks). I did use ajaxStop and remove the first image...Not sure what's going on...Could use a help. Thanks a lot.

My javascript code

```
// add to cart
$(".addToCart").click(function(e){
 $this=$(this);
 $tableId=$this.closest('table').attr('id');


$($this).prev().ajaxStart(function(){
   $("<img class='loader' src='images/loader.gif'>").insertBefore($this);
});


$($this).prev().ajaxStop(function(){
   $($this).prev().remove(); 
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td width="146" align="right" valign="middle">
<br>
<span id="wasPrice"><?php echo $productPriceWas; ?></span>
<br>

<?php echo "$".$productPrice;?><br>**//I want my image here**<a class="addToCart" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/addToCart.gif" alt="add To Cart"/><a/>     </td>
        </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: @Jerry - I see from your comment that my answer was acceptable for you, you can mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the checkbox.  Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) is a global event.  Each click you are binding another set of event handlers which causes 2 or more loading images to show up.   You could try using the [`.one(types, function() { ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/one) event binding to only fire that block of code once per click.

However, I would suggest looking at the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callbacks `beforeSend` and `complete` as places to bind code for a specific ajax request (as opposed to every ajax request).

I usually use a pattern something like this:

```
$(".addToCart").click(function(e){

   // you need to use "var" to make sure $this is only available inside this function
   var $this=$(this);

   // avoid using $ on variables that aren't jQuery objects (this is just a string)
   var tableId=$this.closest('table').attr('id');

   // insert the element before starting the ajax call
   var $loadingElem = $("<img class='loader' src='images/loader.gif'>");
   $loadingElem.insertBefore($this);

   // call ajax with some data
   $.ajax({
     url: '...', data: {id: tableId}, // ....
     complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
       // remove the element when the ajax completes
       $loadingElem.remove();
     }
   });
 });
```

Also, `$($this)` is a wasted call, it will just return `$this`

Comment: Thank you. I really learn a lot from your answer. Really appreciate it!